# When pytest run all tests in a directory, how can it decide which test to run last?

Tags: python, pytest

I am calling all tests under a directory using pytest. How can I run one-specific test case last?

```
python -m pytest ../testdir  
../testdir/test_1.py.... test_n.py
```

Comment: This pytest library seems relevant https://pytest-ordering.readthedocs.io/en/develop/

Comment: That applies to the case where all tests are in one file (test_....py). In my case, there are many test_*.py and some of the tests are under directory.

Comment: you can use -k parameter to run specific test by test function name.

Comment: @ChandaKorat  Using -k is not an option for my case. Everything has to be done through pytest without command line arguments (The pytest was done through Jenkins and Jenkins config can not be changed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily change the default test execution order by implementing your own [`pytest_collection_modifyitems`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection_modifyitems) hook. Create a file `conftest.py` with the following contents:

```
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items):
    test_name = 'test_1'
    test_index = next((i for i, item in enumerate(items) if item.name == test_name), -1)
    test_item = items.pop(test_index)
    items.append(test_item)
```

In this example, if a test function named `test_1` is collected, it will be shifted to the end of the items list. Replace `test_1` with your own function name, or even make it [configurable via command line arguments](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#pass-different-values-to-a-test-function-depending-on-command-line-options).

Comment: This is a great solution. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help! If this answers your question, consider upvoting and accepting the answer (see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).